# Connect to weblogic server running inside docker container from Intellij IDEA

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have Weblogic server running in Docker. Dockerfile can be found here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.1.3

I also enabled Weblogic integration in Intellij IDEA and created following run config:

[image: weblogic run config]

I'm running it on Windows 7, so `192.168.99.100` is default IP address assigned to VirtualBox VM where docker engine runs in.

Port `20180` is the result of port mapping

When I click `Test Connection`, it timeouts with exception

```
Error connecting to the Application Server: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: t3://192.168.99.100:20180: Bootstrap to: docker.homecredit.net/192.168.99.100:20180' over: 't3' got an error or timed out while trying to connect to docker.homecredit.net/192.168.99.100:20180
```

What should I do to make it working?

Why am I required to specify Application Server, when I connect to remote server (I chose remote run config type)

Comment: are you able to access weblogic when connecting from your host machine outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: I can access console

Comment: so you are accessing the console through HTTP protocol, IntelliJ wants to use [T3 protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24389/rmi_t3.htm#WLRMI211). Default one should be 7001, so verify the port and try to map this port from host to docker container and adjust the port in IntelliJ

Comment: I don't use http.. I just specify host and port as you can see in the screenshot.. I thought when I enable tunneling (Admin server settings and protocols tab), which enables T3 protocol, it will work.. but it doesn't

Comment: You youse HTTP when you are accessing console through the browser. IntelliJ is using T3 protocol, therefore, you have to map this port as I already mentioned and put the mapped port inside the IntelliJ connection config. Please paste the URL you are accessing it from your browser, we will see the port.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm using http://192.168.99.100:20180/console/.. so you can see I use mapped port in intellij run config

Comment: Exactly, 20180 is the HTTP port. You cannot use it in T3 protocol connection (used by IntelliJ - see the error). You have to do the steps I mentioned before.

Comment: In my case, default port is 8001 and there is no other port, this port is internal inside docker container.. I mapped it outside as 20180 and even after 'enable tunneling' option (which mentions t3 protocol), I am unable to connect